# How to drop duplicates index of dataframes, which are in list form?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, duplicates

I have a list where every element is Dataframe itself. And theses Dfs have duplicate date time index. I want to remove every duplicate index for every Df in that list.

```
list_dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4]

dtype='datetime64[ns]'  #Index of all Dfs in list_dfs
```

I am Using this list comprehension code. It is removing the duplicate indices but also with columns. At end i ended up only with the indices.

```
[df.index.drop_duplicates(keep='last') for df in list_dfs]
```

Any idea how one can achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and `~` for invering boolean mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'F':list('aaabbb')
}).set_index('F')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('tyuio'),
         'F':list('rrffv')
}).set_index('F')


list_dfs = [df, df1]

L = [df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')] for df in list_dfs]

print (L)
[   A
F   
a  c
b  f,    A
F   
r  y
f  i
v  o]
```